# Lodash: make a hashset-like object out of an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a simple method in lodash to transform an array like `['a', 'b', 'c']` into an object like `{ a: true, b: true, c: true }`? Or is `_.mapValues(_.invert(array), _.constant(true))` the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with the newest release of lodash:

```
var myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_.zipObject(myArr, _.fill(new Array(myArr.length), true));
```

Note that you can't do:

```
_.zipObject(myArr, _.fill(myArr, true));
```

Since [fill()](https://lodash.com/docs#fill) mutates the array passed into it.